# Does OpenCL itself have FPGA backend for HDL?

Tags: opencl, fpga

I wonder who supports FPGA HDL backend for OpenCL.

I thought that altera/intel and xilinx provide compiler for OpenCL to generate HDL backend.

But, does OpenCL framework itself provides HDL backend?

If I'm right, this is not possible, because FPGAs have unique options depending on which board we use.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "OpenCL framework" as such: OpenCL is a specification, a standard, and each supported device (GPU, CPU, FPGA) and platform (OS) combination needs its own implementation that complies with the standard, usually developed by the device vendor or OS vendor.